# How to send the success of a test to testingBot from a Protractor project?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

Following the testingBot example for protractor-based projects I got this code

```
var TestingBot = require('testingbot-api');

 describe('Protractor Demo App', function () {
 var tb;
 beforeEach(function () {
     tb = new TestingBot({
         api_key: "master_key",
         api_secret: "secret_007"
     });
 });

 afterEach(function () {
     browser.getSession().then(function (session) {
         tb.updateTest({

             'test[success]': true/*where do I get this 'test[success]' attribute?  */

         }, session.getId(), function () {
             console.log("Hi! :D");
         });
     })
 });

 it('should have a title', function () {
     browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
     expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
 });
});
```

I need to send the success of the test back through the tb.updateTest() but I don't know where I get the value of a passed or failed test. For now the value is a static true. I'd appreciate a jasmine approach too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [custom reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_reporter.html) with Jasmine.
There you can hook into `specDone` or `suiteDone` which has a `result` parameter, containing the test's success state.

You can then use this state to write a custom report or send it to somewhere else.